# $F : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, $F(n) = 2 -3n$. Is $F$ one-to-one? Onto?

Tags: functions, relations

> Define $F : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ by the rule $F(n) = 2 -3n$, for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Is $F$ one-to-one? Onto?

Now, I understand that one-to-one means that nothing in the co-domain is being pointed to twice.  I also understand onto; which means that every point in the codomain is being pointed to by a point in the domain.  Beyond that, I am unsure of where to start here, in terms of proving or disproving them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hints:**

- Suppose $F(m) = F(n)$, that is $2-3m = 2-3n$; what can you say about the relationship between $m$ and $n$?
- Let $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Can you solve $f(n) = k$? First solve the equation $2 - 3n = k$ for $n$, then check to see whether or not $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: For the first bullet point it would seem that m=n.

Comment: Correct. What does that tells us about the function?

Comment: Would that mean it is one-to-one?

Comment: Correct. Recall, a function $F$ is one-to-one if $F(m) = F(n) \Rightarrow m = n$. You proved exactly this.

Comment: OK I understand why m=n but can you explain the reasoning why we created the m function and how we know to setup the equation the way we did?

Comment: To show $F$ is one-to-one, we need to show that if $F(m) = F(n)$ then $m = n$. So if we want to show that $F$ is one-to-one we need to consider the equation $F(m) = F(n)$.

Comment: But if we create the F(m) exactly as the F(n) function is wouldn't they always be equal?

Comment: If $m$ and $n$ are the same, yes. Instead of thinking of $F(m)$ and $F(n)$ as functions, instead think of $m$ and $n$ as particular choices of elements in the domain of $F$.

Comment: But we are setting the F(m) function to exactly what the F(n) is, correct?  When would the 2 sides of the equation not start out looking exactly the same, I guess is my question?

Comment: Maybe an example that is NOT one-to-one would help me understand.

Comment: Try $F(n) = n^2$. Then $F(m) = F(n)$ does not imply $m = n$. Can you see why?

Comment: I don't see why.  Because for example 2 squared = 4 but -2 squared also = 4?  So we can't know that m and n are the same?

Comment: Correct, so $F(m) = F(n) \not\Rightarrow m = n$. Therefore $F$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Can you explain the test for onto?

Comment: $F:X\to Y$ is onto if, for every $y \in Y$, there is $x \in X$ such that $F(x) = y$. My hint was to solve $2-3n = k$; this gives you an expression for $n$ in terms of $k$. This expression is what $n$ *has* to be for $F(n)$ to be equal to $k$, but the domain of $F$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ so we need to check that $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $n \not\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $F(n) \neq k$.

Comment: k-2 / 3 = n. correct?

Comment: Not quite, you've misplaced a negative sign.

Comment: k - 2 / -3 = n.

Comment: That's correct. Can you determine whether $F$ is onto or not?

Comment: Not quite sure where to go from that equation to do so.

Comment: Is $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Doesn't it depend on what k is?

Comment: Yes. For some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ so we will be able to find a solution to $F(n) = k$. But for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n \not\in \mathbb{Z}$ so we can't find a solution to $F(n) = k$. $F$ is onto if we can find a solution to $F(n) = k$ for every $k$. So, is $F$ onto?

Comment: So since, we got that equation, it means that it is onto?

Comment: Can we find $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $F(n) = 1$?

Comment: yes, there are several numbers we could in place of k that would make n an integer... (I really hope I am close, thanks for your patience)

Comment: There are several values of $k$ such that $n$ is an integer, that is true, but for $F$ to be onto, you need $n$ to be an integer for all possible values of $k$. Is $n$ an integer if $k = 1$?

Comment: Ahhhhhh. OK that helped.  If we make k = 1, we get -1/-3 which is 0.333333 which is not an integer so that is the counterexample proving it is not onto.

Comment: Exactly! Well done.

Comment: What if we wanted to use the same equation, but the relation was for all real numbers instead of integers.  How would it change?

Comment: I think that would be onto?

Comment: Yes it would be onto because for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, there would be $n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(n) = k$. The same is true if we defined $F$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$.